# Add NSStrings to mutable array

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsstring, nsmutablearray

I created a mutable array and I have two `NSString` variables. Now I want to add these two `NSString`s to my array. How is this possible? Thanks.

Comment: use addObject: from nsmutable array i hope this is enough for you...

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use the `addObject` function of you `NSMutableArray`.

eg.

```
[myNSMutableArray addObject:myString1];
[myNSMutableArray addObject:myString2];
```

Answer (score 0):

Jhaliya's answer is correct. +1 vote.

I added a immutable version so you can see the difference. If you dont want to remove or add more objects (NSStrings) to your container, I would recommend using an Immutable version.

Mutable version:

```
NSMutableArray *mutableArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSString *string_one = @"One"];
[mutableArray addObject:string_one];
//Or
[mutableArray addObject:@"Two"];
NSLog(@"%@", mutableArray);
```

Immutable version

```
NSArray *immutableArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"One", @"Two", nil];
NSLog(@"%@", immutableArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add at `NSMutableArray` allocation.

Like :

```
NSMutableArray *test = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"test1",@"test2",nil];
```